# What is the parent class of rectangles, circles etc

Tags: class, parent, kineticjs

I want to extend the properties of circles, rectangles, Lines etc. I am able to do this for each of individual shapes using prototype, but would rather add the properties to the parent class and allow the these base shapes "inheret" them from the parent class.

```
Kinetic.Shape.prototype.testMe=99;
```

How would I reference this property from say a "Rectangle"

Comment: `rect.testMe`? Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

**The parent class of Circles, Rects, etc is Kinetic.Shape**

**The parent class of Kinetic.Shape is Kinetic.Node**

Officially, you can use `Kinetic.Util.extend` to add properties/methods to a Kinetic base class.

But "behind-the-scenes" this extend method just appends the base class properties/methods to the .prototype of the new class.

So your Kinetic.Shape.prototype.testMe is really just as good as the "official" way of extending the class.

KineticJS does not implement inheritance so you cannot add properties to the Kinetic.Shape base class and have its children inherit those properties.

You can somewhat automate the addition of new properties to the Kinetic.Shape and all its derived shapes using code like this:

```
var Shapes={

    shapes:[
        Kinetic.Arc,Kinetic.Circle,Kinetic.Ellipse,
        Kinetic.Image,Kinetic.Line,Kinetic.Rect,Kinetic.Ring,
        Kinetic.Sprite,Kinetic.Text,Kinetic.Wedge,Kinetic.Shape
    ],

    add:function(key,value){
        for(var i=0;i<this.shapes.length;i++){
            this.shapes[i].prototype[key]=value;
        }
    }

}

// add some test properties to all the Kinetic.Shape's

Shapes.add("testMe",99);
Shapes.add("meToo",101);
```

Comment: but "Kinetic.Circle instanceof Kinetic.Shape" evaluates to false

Comment: Yes, `instanceof` will be false because Kinetic does not give the child the parent's prototype.  Instead it does "extend" by adding all parent's prototype properties/methods to the child's prototype.  Like this:  `for(var key in parent.prototype){if(!(key in child.prototype)){child.prototype[key] = parent.prototype[key];}}
`

Comment: Instead of extending each circle, rectangle, line etc. attributes I want to extend their parent class "Shape" and reference these attributes from the child class. How would you refrence these from the child class?

Comment: When I try to reference this attribute using "alert(circle.testMe);" it comes back undefined?? Im missing something.

Comment: KineticJS does not implement inheritance so you cannot add properties to the Kinetic.Shape base class and have its children inherit those properties (unless you want to add those properties to the source code).  I've added code to may answer that automates adding a property to the Kinetic.Shape and its derived shapes.  Not as satisfying as true inheritance, but it solves the need. :-\